# C# Entity Test - While debugging, test pass but in run mode fail

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I want to check if my remove method works :) I added one tuple to my database.

TestMethod

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void DeleteIngredient()
    {
        using (var ctx = new TestDbContext())
        {
            //Arrange
            Ingredient ingredient = new TestClass.Ingredient();
            ingredient.Id = 1;
            ingredient.Name = "Watermelon";
            ingredient.VegeOrVegetarian = VeganType.Both;
            //Act
            ctx.ingredients.Add(ingredient);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            IngredientService service = new IngredientService(ctx);
            service.removeIngredient(1);
            service.saveChanges();

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(0, ctx.ingredients.Count());
        }
    }
```

Service

```
        public class IngredientService
{
    private readonly TestDbContext _TestDbContext;

    public IngredientService(TestDbContext TestDbContext)
    {
        _TestDbContext = TestDbContext;
    }

    public List<Ingredient> getIngredients()
    {
        return _TestDbContext.ingredients.ToList();
    }

    public void removeIngredient(int id)
    {
        var toRemove = _TestDbContext.ingredients.Find(id);       
        _TestDbContext.ingredients.Remove(toRemove);

    }
    public void saveChanges()
    {
        _TestDbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Everthing works in debugging mode.

```
Assert.AreEqual(0, ctx.ingredients.Count());
```

i am informed about test pass.
But after running all test in run mode including this delete i am getting error.

> Assert.AreEqual failed Expected: <0>. Actual<1>

I think there is problem with context. Any clue how to solve this ?

Comment: I don't know how did you have your database configured, but can you try call `service.removeIngredient(ingredient.Id);` instead? You might end up with other id that is not 1

Comment: ye i know it was just added temporary XD

Comment: are you sure that you aren't running other tests that use the same db? can you add a clear at the beginning and savechanges just to make sure

Answer (score 0):

Short version:

Do not use DbContext to get data required to validation. To get this data use no ORM approach: DbConnection, DbCommand etc.

Algorithm of testing:

1. Get StartData from db by no ORM approach.
2. Do what you want to test with ORM approach.
3. Dispose ORM context or close session.
4. Get EndData from db by no ORM approach.
5. Validate data.

The answer to why do this with such why is complex. Due to the use of different versions and types of libraries for testing, ORM and database providers do not have a simple answer as to what may go wrong.

Sorry for My English.